# The validity of casting in the 'function pointer' version of K&R's qsort

Tags: c, casting, language-lawyer, void-pointers, kernighan-and-ritchie

This question is about the 'function pointer' version of `qsort` from K&R (2e), section 5.11 (p118-121). There are a number of places where I don't understand why or how the casts work, and I suspect that the program is not entirely standards-conformant.

Here is the source code. Aside from removing comments and making minor changes to the formatting, I:

- renamed `qsort` to `qsort_alt` (for "alternative qsort"), because the standard library already contains a function named `qsort`,
- changed the function signature of `main` to `int main(void)`, and
- simplified and altered `main` to use input supplied via the `linearr` and `wlinearr` variables instead of `stdin`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>

char *linearr[] = {
    "13", "5", "10", "9", "23", "2", "5",
    "25", "3", "13", "1", "4", "14", "19",
};
wchar_t *wlinearr[] = {
    L"13", L"5", L"10", L"9", L"23", L"2", L"5",
    L"25", L"3", L"13", L"1", L"4", L"14", L"19",
    L"42", L"32", L"25", L"5", L"3", L"34",
    L"50", L"40", L"86", L"91", L"100", L"21",
    L"29", L"28", L"23", L"93", L"24", L"89",
    L"85", L"63", L"10", L"39", L"14", L"18",
    L"78", L"73", L"52", L"57", L"26", L"38",
    L"91", L"76", L"61", L"46",
};

void qsort_alt(void *v[], int left, int right,
               int (*comp)(void *, void *));
int numcmp(char *, char *);

int main(void) {
    int nlines = sizeof(linearr) / sizeof(linearr[0]);
    int nwlines = sizeof(wlinearr) / sizeof(wlinearr[0]);
    int i;

    qsort_alt((void **)linearr, 0, nlines - 1,
              (int (*)(void *, void *))numcmp);
    for (i = 0; i < nlines; i++)
        printf("%s%s", linearr[i], (i < nlines - 1) ? " " : "\n");
    /* output: 1 2 3 4 5 5 9 10 13 13 14 19 23 25 */

    qsort_alt((void **)linearr, 0, nlines - 1,
              (int (*)(void *, void *))strcmp);
    for (i = 0; i < nlines; i++)
        printf("%s%s", linearr[i], (i < nlines - 1) ? " " : "\n");
    /* output: 1 10 13 13 14 19 2 23 25 3 4 5 5 9 */

    qsort_alt((void **)wlinearr, 0, nwlines - 1,
              (int (*)(void *, void *))wcscmp);
    for (i = 0; i < nwlines; i++)
        wprintf(L"%ls%ls", wlinearr[i], (i < nwlines - 1) ? L" " : L"\n");
    /* output: 1 10 10 100 13 13 14 14 18 19 2 21 23 23 24 25 25 26 28 29 3 3 32 34 38 39 4 40 42 46 5 5 5 50 52 57 61 63 73 76 78 85 86 89 9 91 91 93 */

    return 0;
}

void qsort_alt(void *v[], int left, int right,
               int (*comp)(void *, void *)) {
    int i, last;
    void swap(void *v[], int, int);

    if (left >= right)
        return;
    swap(v, left, (left + right) / 2);
    last = left;
    for (i = left + 1; i <= right; i++)
        if ((*comp)(v[i], v[left]) < 0)
            swap(v, ++last, i);
    swap(v, left, last);
    qsort_alt(v, left, last - 1, comp);
    qsort_alt(v, last + 1, right, comp);
}

#include <stdlib.h>

int numcmp(char *s1, char *s2) {
    double v1, v2;

    v1 = atof(s1);
    v2 = atof(s2);
    if (v1 < v2)
        return -1;
    else if (v1 > v2)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

void swap(void *v[], int i, int j) {
    void *temp;

    temp = v[i];
    v[i] = v[j];
    v[j] = temp;
}
```

For me, this compiles fine (without warnings) with GCC and compiler flags `-std=iso9899:199409 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra` and produces the output shown within the comments above. (The choice of `iso9899:199409` reflects the fact that `<wchar.h>` was introduced with C95, but actually this compiles and runs equally well with `c90`.)

My call to `qsort_alt` is substantially the same as in K&R (2e). For reference, in the original it was

```
qsort((void **) lineptr, 0, nlines-1,
  (int (*)(void*,void*))(numeric ? numcmp : strcmp));
```

with `int nlines` indicating the number of lines stored in `char *lineptr[MAXLINES]` and `numeric` being a boolean flag (set via the command line) that decides which of the two functions `numcmp`/`strcmp` is used. K&R's `main` reads input from `stdin` into `char *lineptr[MAXLINES]`; I replaced it by `char *linearr[]`. The input `wchar_t *wlinearr[]` is my own addition. Relevant here is what K&R write (p119-120):

> We have written `qsort` [in my code: `qsort_alt`] so it can process any data type, not just character strings. [...] The elaborate cast of the function argument casts the arguments of the comparison function. These will generally have no effect on actual representation, but assure the compiler that all is well.

Let's see whether all is good, ie: whether the program is portable and whether it would work for other types such as `wchar_t`, as implied by K&R:

**1. Why are the arguments to `qsort_alt` [orig: `qsort`] cast explicitly?**

The C17 standard draft says (6.5.2.2 ¶7):

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does include a prototype [ie: it doesn't use old-style syntax], the arguments are implicitly converted, as if by assignment, to the types of the corresponding parameters, taking the type of each parameter to be the unqualified version of its declared type.

That is, it seems that explicit casts to match the types of the function parameters of `qsort_alt` aren't necessary, though they may be stylistically justified.

However, is the following wording (6.5.4 ¶3) relevant?

> Conversions that involve pointers, other than where permitted by the constraints of 6.5.16.1 ["Simple assignment"], shall be specified by means of an explicit cast.

**2. Is the cast `(void **)linearr` [orig: `(void **) lineptr`] legal?** What about my `(void **)wlinearr`?

6.3.2.3 ¶7:

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned[] for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.

Pointer types are object types, hence `char *` and `void *` are object types, and therefore pointers to these types can legally be converted. However, the second sentence is relevant as well. While we know that `char *` and `void *` are identically aligned (6.2.5 ¶28), this wouldn't necessarily be true for `wchar_t *` and `void *`: it is easy to imagine a situation where the former has half the bit width of the latter. (Recall that K&R claim that their `qsort` "can process any data type".) That is, even if the cast is fine, my cast `(void **)wlinearr` might not be.

There is other language in the standard (6.7.6.1 ¶2) where I am not sure whether it has any bearing on these issues:

> For two pointer types to be compatible, both shall be identically qualified and both shall be pointers to compatible types.

`linearr` is of type `char * []` and decays to type `char **` just before the cast to type `void **`. For `char **` and `void **` to be compatible, `char *` and `void *` would need to be compatible, but it seems that they technically [aren't compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65651699/2057969).

**3. Are the casts of `numcmp`/`strcmp` from types `int (*)(char *, char *)`/`int (*)(const char *, const char *)` to type `int (*)(void *, void *)` legal?** What about my analogous cast of `wcscmp` from type `int (*)(const wchar_t *, const wchar_t *)` to type `int (*)(void *, void *)`? (Note that the difference in `const`ness isn't an issue.)

As the document "Errata for *The C Programming Language, Second Edition*" by Lucent Technologies (2002/2006) states (code formatting added in some places):

> [T]he comparison-routine argument is not treated well. The call shown on p 119, with an argument
> `(int (*)(void*,void*))(numeric? numcmp : strcmp)`
> is not only complicated, but only barely passes muster. Both `numcmp` and `strcmp` take `char *` arguments, but this expression casts pointers to these functions to a function pointer that takes `void *` arguments. The standard does say that `void *` and `char *` have the same representation, so the example will almost certainly work in practice, and is at least defensible under the standard.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/559671/2057969), the casting of function pointers is only safe (as in: doesn't lead to undefined behavior) if the respective types are "compatible", but `char *` and `void *` are technically not compatible (see #2 above).

But perhaps this is really just to appease the compiler (as K&R assure us), so let's have a look at what happens in `qsort_alt`:

**4. Is the call to `comp` unproblematic?**

`qsort_alt` computes `v[i]` and `v[left]`, which involves pointer arithmetic on an underlying `void *` type. (Note that `v` is of type `void **`. While pointer arithmetic is illegal on `void *` (with an underlying `void`), it is not illegal on `void **` (with an underlying `void *`).) Because pointers to `void` and to character types "have the same representation and alignment requirements" (6.2.5 ¶28), **the index computations seem fine for K&R's original code, but do they also work portably for `wchar_t`? It seems that a type-generic version of the program would need to supply the size of the underlying type (such as `wchar_t *`) to `qsort_alt`.**

Furthermore, I am not sure whether it is really true that "[t]he elaborate cast of the function argument [within `main`] casts the arguments of the comparison function". It seems to me that if any arguments *of* the comparison function are cast, that would happen within `qsort_alt` when it calls `comp`, but not within the call to `qsort_alt` within `main`. From the perspective of `qsort_alt`, `comp` is a function accepting `void *` arguments, and any `v[index]` is of type `void *`, and therefore there don't seem to be any implicit argument conversions going on. In this regard, I am assuming that implicit argument conversions for function parameters would be performed by the caller, not the callee, but do correct me if I'm wrong. (Caller and callee may, like here, have differing beliefs about the parameters' types.) Despite the absence of a conversion, `comp` will internally assume that its arguments are `char *` (for K&R's original) or `wchar_t *` (for my addition). Things should go well as long as the pointer arithmetic to get to the arguments `v[i]` and `v[left]` is proper.

Incidentally, I see calls within `qsort_alt` to `swap` as unproblematic, as `swap` operates on a `void **` argument and only reassigns pointers.

Comment: Why not just rewrite `numcmp()` to take `void *` arguments and avoid that cast?

Comment: @Shawn I minimally adapted the version in K&R, which aims to illustrate function pointers with their code. `numcmp` uses `atof`, which operates on strings, which are converted to numbers and then compared numerically.

Comment: Typically the comparison function converts its arguments to the appropriate type to compare.

Comment: Function pointer casting and then calling the result is UB, I believe. I also believe it crashes on Emscripten.

Comment: @Shawn Ah, now in the context of reading the well-written code in the [answer by user 'chqrlie'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76242405/2057969) I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, we should call the attention of any readers of this question to the fact the `qsort` being discussed here, as defined in Kernighan and Ritchie, *The C Programming Language* (second edition), page 120, is not the `qsort` specified in the C standard. The one in the book is archaic and has a defective design. Its prototype is:

```
void qsort(void *v[], int left, int right, int (*comp)(void *, void *));
```

The one in the 1990 C standard has prototype:

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

The most significant difference is the first is designed only to sort an array of pointers, specifically pointers to `void` (first parameter type is `void *[]`), whereas the standard version can sort an array of any type (first parameter type is `void *`, and the third parameter gives the size for each element).

> **1. Why are the arguments to `qsort_alt` [orig: `qsort`] cast explicitly?**

Two arguments are cast, the first and the last. In the first, the authors wish to pass their `lineptr`, which has type `char *[5000]`, for a parameter nominally of type `void *[]`. The array `lineptr` will be automatically converted to `char **`, and the nominal parameter type will be automatically adjusted to `void **`, so these are different and incompatible types. For a function call with a prototype, C 2018 6.5.2.2 2 says “… Each argument shall have a type such that its value may be assigned to an object with the unqualified version of the type of its corresponding parameter.” (C 1990 6.3.2.2 is similar.)

Constraints for simple assignment are in C 2018 6.5.16.1 1. (C 1990 6.3.16.1 is similar.) Two of its cases cover when the left operand and the right operand of an assignment are pointer types. One of these says, in part, both are pointers to compatible types except for the qualifiers. This does not apply because `char *` and `void *` are not compatible. The other says, in part, the left operand may be a pointer to `void`, with or without qualifiers. This does not apply because `void **` is not a pointer to `void`. Therefore, a `char **` expression does not satisfy the constraints for assignment to a `void **` object, so the `char **` argument for a `void **` does not satisfy the constraints for a function call, so this argument cannot be passed for a `void **` parameter without a cast.

In the last argument, the authors wish to pass their `numcmp`, which, after automatic conversion of a function to a pointer, has type `int (*)(char *, char *)`, for a parameter of type `int (*)(void *, void *)`. Again the constraints for simple assignment apply, and this argument cannot be passed for that parameter without a cast.

> **2. Is the cast `(void **)linearr` [orig: `(void **) lineptr`] legal?** What about my `(void **)wlinearr`?

The conversion is defined and the conversion and the use of the result to access pointers in the original array is effectively defined by the C standard, albeit by the kludgy specification in C 2018 6.2.5 28 that “A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type.”

The initial conversion from `char **` to `void **` is defined by C 2018 6.3.2.3 7, which says a pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type, but it is undefined if the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type. Since `char *` and `void *` have the same alignment requirements, the caveat does not apply. 6.3.2.3 7 further says that converting the result back to the original type yields a value equal to the original pointer. This is the only thing the standard tells us generally about the result of this conversion—for example, it does not tell us that if we convert `int *i` to `float *f`, and `int` and `float` have the same size and alignment requirements, that `*f` will access the same bytes as `*i` will. However, a footnote to 6.2.5 28 tells us “The same representation and alignment requirements are meant to imply interchangeability as arguments to functions,…” This is a bad way to say that a `char *` may serve as a `void *` or vice versa, but it does seem the intent was to say we can convert a `char **` to a `void **` and use the result to access the `char *` elements. The intent is presumably also to allow this aliasing of different types even though it nominally violates the rules for aliasing in C 2018 6.5 7.

So the conversion from `char **` to `void **` is defined and may be used to access the `char *` pointers, even when it is done using a `void *` type.

On the other hand, your `(void **) wlinearr` conversion does not enjoy this license. After array-to-pointer conversion, `wlinearr` yields `wchar_t **`, and `wchar_t *` does not necessarily have the same size, representation, or alignment requirements as `void *`. So the conversion is not guaranteed to work. Even if it does, the resulting value is not specified to be useful for accessing the elements of the `wchar_t *` array.

> **3. Are the casts of `numcmp`/`strcmp` from types `int (*)(char *, char *)`/`int (*)(const char *, const char *)` to type `int (*)(void *, void *)` legal?** What about my analogous cast of `wcscmp` from type `int (*)(const wchar_t *, const wchar_t *)` to type `int (*)(void *, void *)`? (Note that the difference in `const`ness isn't an issue.)

The conversions specified by the casts are defined, because C 2018 6.3.2.3 8 says a pointer to any type of function may be converted to a pointer to any other type of function. However, the only defined uses for such a pointer are converting it back to the original type, comparing it for equality to other pointers, or testing whether it is a null pointer. That paragraph says “… If a converted pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.”

> **4. Is the call to `comp` unproblematic?**

It is problematic because of the rule quoted just above. The `qsort` defined at this point in the book is defective in standard C and should not be used. Perhaps it was designed for pedagogical purposes, to use types in a more simplistic way than proper use requires to avoid presenting too many new concepts to the student at once. Nonetheless, it is not a good design.

The `qsort` in the C standard fixes these problems. First, instead of a `void **` (equivalently `void *[]`, due to automatic adjustment) parameter, it takes `void *` and a `size_t size` parameters. These provide the base address of the elements to be sorted and the size of each element. This allows `qsort` to manipulate any array by treating its elements as raw bytes (which has defined behavior by the C standard). It does not need type information about the array elements, other than the size.

Second, it specifies the prototype of the comparison function as `int ()(const void *, const void *)`. So no information about the element types is visible or used in this prototype. The function is passed raw pointers to memory, with no type information (other than the `const` qualifier). Inside the function, the `const void *` pointers should be converted to pointers to the actual element type (with `const`). Thus, all of the type information is inside the comparison function the `qsort` caller provides; none of it is built into `qsort`.

(The standard `qsort` also changes `int left, int right` to `size_t nmemb`. This simply removes a redundancy, as the caller can specify the “left” endpoint by adding to the base address passed in `base`, and then the number of elements provides the location of the “right” endpoint.)

Comment: Regarding "for pedagogical purposes, [...] to avoid presenting too many new concepts [...] at once": It seems like K&R still failed in this regard. As the errata document by Lucent Technologies (2002/2006) phrases it (immediately after the portion I quote in my original post above): "There are too many lessons in these pages." It would have been better for them to teach function pointer casting elsewhere and stick to `char *` instead of `void *` in all places here, as the resulting code would already have enough didactic value and actually be correct.

Answer (score 2):

The function `qsort` discussed in this question is different from the `qsort` function specified in the C Standard.  It specifically sorts sorts an array of generic pointers to objects (type `void *`), using a pointer to a function that compares objects, itself receiving 2 `void *` pointers from the array.

The standard `qsort` from the C library sorts an array of objects, not an array of pointers to objects.  If passed an array of pointers, the comparison function will receive addresses of such pointers, and need to dereference them to compare the actual objects.

Unlike the now standard `qsort`, the functions discussed here cannot sort an array of `int` or `double` or other scalar types, nor an array of structures.

Furthermore, the second and third arguments have a very different meaning: the standard `qsort` takes the number of elements and the element size, whereas `qsort_alt` takes `left`, the index to the first element of a slice and `right`, the index of the last element in the slice.  This does not allow for sorting empty arrays, in which there is no *last* element.  It would be more idiomatic to pass `right` as the index to the first element after the slice, hence `right - left` would be the number of elements, or to just pass the number of elements in the array allowing for empty slices and removing the need for confusing `+1`/`-1` adjustments in the algorithm.

Also note that declaring `void swap(void *v[], int, int);` locally in the scope of the `qsort_alt` is a bad idea as the prototype has a limited scope and will not be checked for consistency when the parser eventually reaches the function definition.  It is strongly recommended to always declare functions at the global scope.

Regarding your questions:

> 1. Why are the arguments to `qsort_alt` [orig: `qsort`] cast explicitly?
> 2. Is the cast `(void **)linearr` [orig: `(void **) lineptr`] legal? What about my `(void **)wlinearr`?

`qsort_alt` expects an array of `void *`, more precisely a pointer to `void` pointers, `(void **)`.  You pass arrays of `char *` and arrays of `wchar_t *`, which are not compatible with arrays of `void *`, as the pointed types are different and incompatible.  This might seem confusing as `void *` is *compatible* with all data pointer types for assignment, but it may have a different representation from `wchar_t *` hence pretending a `wchar_t *` **is** a `void *` is incorrect.  As noted in the K&R erratum, `void *` and `char *` are mandated to have the same representation by the C Standard, so you should get away with this for the `(void **)linearr` case, but the cast, albeit legal in C may cause undefined behavior, and more so for the other case `(void **)wlinearr`

In the case of standard `qsort`, not only is the cast not necessary, it is actually counter productive, albeit not a problem in practice as noted in the erratum.  The cast is useless because `qsort` expects a `void *`, ie: a data pointer to any type. `linearr` is an array, so it decays to a `char **` when passed as a function argument, which is converted implicitly to a `void *`.  Casting it to `void **` is problematic as explained here above, but the resulting `void **` is still compatible with `void *`.

> 3. Are the casts of `numcmp`/`strcmp` from types `int (*)(char *, char *)`/`int (*)(const char *, const char *)` to type `int (*)(void *, void *)` legal?
>
> What about my analogous cast of `wcscmp` from type `int (*)(const wchar_t *, const wchar_t *)` to type `int (*)(void *, void *)`? (Note that the difference in constness isn't an issue.)

The answer is no, they are not legal in either case.  Yet since `void *` and `char *` have the same representation, one could assume that they should be passed the same way as function arguments (which is an ABI issue not covered by the Standard), do a function such as `strcmp` that takes 2 `const char *` and returns an `int` or `numcmp` probably behaves as expected where `qsort` invokes a function taking 2 `void *` and returns an `int`.

Casting `wcscmp` as a `int (*)(void *, void *)` is definitely incorrect, but will cause an issue in very few systems, where `wchar_t *` and `void *` have a different representation and/or calling convention. I am personally not aware of any such system in production, but the C Standard allows for such differences, albeit the POSIX Standard does not.

> 4. Is the call to comp unproblematic?

For reasons explained above, the call may be problematic, and the pointer arithmetic would be indeed incorrect if `wchar *` and `void *` have a different size.

Here is a modified version of the code using functions that a compatible with standard `qsort` and without any explicit casts:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>

const char *linearr[] = {
    "13", "5", "10", "9", "23", "2", "5",
    "25", "3", "13", "1", "4", "14", "19",
};
const wchar_t *wlinearr[] = {
    L"13", L"5", L"10", L"9", L"23", L"2", L"5",
    L"25", L"3", L"13", L"1", L"4", L"14", L"19",
    L"42", L"32", L"25", L"5", L"3", L"34",
    L"50", L"40", L"86", L"91", L"100", L"21",
    L"29", L"28", L"23", L"93", L"24", L"89",
    L"85", L"63", L"10", L"39", L"14", L"18",
    L"78", L"73", L"52", L"57", L"26", L"38",
    L"91", L"76", L"61", L"46",
};

int cmp_numcmp(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    const char * const *s1 = p1;
    const char * const *s2 = p2;
    double d1 = atof(*s1);
    double d2 = atof(*s2);
    return (d2 < d1) - (d2 > d1);
}

int cmp_strcmp(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    const char * const *s1 = p1;
    const char * const *s2 = p2;
    return strcmp(*s1, *s2);
}

int cmp_wcscmp(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    const wchar_t * const *s1 = p1;
    const wchar_t * const *s2 = p2;
    return wcscmp(*s1, *s2);
}

void swap(unsigned char *p1, unsigned char *p2, size_t size) {
    while (size --> 0) {
        unsigned char temp = *p1;
        *p1++ = *p2;
        *p2++ = temp;
    }
}

/* same prototype as qsort from <stdlib.h> */
void qsort_alt(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
               int (*comp)(const void *, const void *))
{
    if (nmemb > 1) {
        unsigned char *p = base;
        size_t i, last;
        /* choose the middle element as the pivot
         * and swap it to the beginning of the array
         */
        swap(p, p + (nmemb / 2) * size, size);
        last = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < nmemb; i++) {
            if ((*comp)(p + i * size, p) < 0) {
                /* if the element is below the pivot, swap it into the left slice */
                swap(p + ++last * size, p + i * size, size);
            }
        }
        /* swap the pivot back to its final place between the slices */
        swap(p, p + last * size, size);
        /* sort the left slice (elements before the pivot) */
        qsort_alt(p, last, size, comp);
        /* sort the right slice (elements after the pivot) */
        qsort_alt(p + (last + 1) * size, nmemb - (last + 1), size, comp);
    }
}

/* compatibility with Standard qsort from the C library can be 
   verified by uncommenting the line below */
/* #define qsort_alt qsort */

int main(void) {
    size_t nlines = sizeof(linearr) / sizeof(linearr[0]);
    size_t nwlines = sizeof(wlinearr) / sizeof(wlinearr[0]);
    size_t i;

    qsort_alt(linearr, nlines, sizeof(linearr[0]), cmp_numcmp);
    for (i = 0; i < nlines; i++) {
        printf("%s%s", linearr[i], (i < nlines - 1) ? " " : "\n");
    }
    /* output: 1 2 3 4 5 5 9 10 13 13 14 19 23 25 */

    qsort_alt(linearr, nlines, sizeof(linearr[0]), cmp_strcmp);
    for (i = 0; i < nlines; i++) {
        printf("%s%s", linearr[i], (i < nlines - 1) ? " " : "\n");
    }
    /* output: 1 10 13 13 14 19 2 23 25 3 4 5 5 9 */

    qsort_alt(wlinearr, nwlines, sizeof(wlinearr[0]), cmp_wcscmp);
    for (i = 0; i < nwlines; i++) {
        wprintf(L"%ls%ls", wlinearr[i], (i < nwlines - 1) ? L" " : L"\n");
    }
    /* output: 1 10 10 100 13 13 14 14 18 19 2 21 23 23 24 25 25 26 28 29 3 3 32 34 38 39 4 40 42 46 5 5 5 50 52 57 61 63 73 76 78 85 86 89 9 91 91 93 */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Re “For your modified version, you made a drastic semantical change… The original qsort from the C library…”: They are not asking about the `qsort` in the standard C library. They are asking about the `qsort` in K&R second edition, page 120, which hs defined with `void qsort(void *v[], int left, int right, int (*comp)(void *, void *))`. The only thing they changed was the name.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: oops! you are correct, my mistake, but the explanations still hold regarding the casts, and it is very confusing to refer to a function `qsort` from the K&R book that is different from the Standard function by the same name. Your explanation is superior.

Comment: I am impressed by your cast-free code (which should have been the version taught in K&R, 2e). Your code also rightfully draws attention to the need for `swap` to be size-aware.

Answer (score 1):

If we need to boil this down to a short answer, we can have an answer as follows:

The definition of `qsort_alt` is wrong because it takes a `char *[]` array passed as a `void *[]` array. You can't actually do that by standard. The hidden assumption is all data pointers are the same type. While this was true on the ancestral platform and true on modern platforms, it is not true of all platforms of the '80s and '90s. On some platforms, `sizeof(int *)` and `sizeof(char *)` differ, and on at least one platform the memory layout of `int *` and `char *` were different despite being the same size.

While I can't say for certain there exists a platform for which the call fails, I can prove the intent of `void *` was lost. Given the cases above, there must exist a platform that fails for one of `int[]` (and `struct T` for almost any arbitrary `T`) or `char[]`.